# Sort multiple arrays

Tags: ios, sorting, nsarray

Here is my situation:

I manipulate 6 NSMutableArrays. One of them has `NSDate`s objects in it, the other ones have `NSNumber`s. When I populate them, I use `addObject:` for each of them, so index 0 of each array contains all the values I want for my date at index 0 in the dates array.

I want to make sure that the arrays are all sorted according to the dates array (order by date, ascending), meaning that during the sorting, if row 5 of the dates array is moved to row 1, it has to be applied to all the other arrays as well.

I was **previously** using CoreData, but I **must** not use it anymore (please don't ask why, this is off-topic ;) ). In CoreData, I could use an `NSSortDescriptor`, but I have no idea on how to do it with multiple `NSArray`s...

As always, hints/answers/solutions are always appreciated :)

Comment: Can't you package all 6 data items including the date into a single object, instead of keeping it in 6 different arrays? Then you'll have a single array. Just sort that array by its date property.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that's actually what Sulthan and Ben suggested. I can't believe I didn't even think of that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common problem. Use the following approach.

1. Encapsulate your six arrays into an object - every instance will have six properties.
2. Implement `compare:` method on this object, using `[NSDate compare:]` (this step can be skipped but it's cleaner this way).
3. Now you have only one array - sort it using the method from step 2.

Comment: Thanks. As I commented in my question, I can't believe I did not think of that :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the better solution for you to have NSArray of NSDictionary objects.

```
NSArray *allValues = [[NSArray alloc] init];
NSDictionary *dict = @{"Date" : [NSDate date], @"Key1" : @"Value1", @"Key2" : @"Value2"};
```

Then you can sort this array with sortDescriptor without any problems.
And then you can also use Comparator or Sort Desriptor as you wish.

Comment: That's actually not a bad idea to use a dictionary. I've used arrays so many times it blinded me from the other containers.. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Wrap all your items that you are storing in an array into a single object. Each one of your previous 6 arrays will be a property.

Inside that object you can implement

```
 - (NSComparisonResult)compare:(YourClass *)otherObject {
     return [self.date compare:otherObject.date];
}
```

You can now sort the array and they will sort by date.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably go with something like this. And sorry, but @Sulthan posted a similar solution 2 minutes earlier so I have to accept his answer :)